# Admin On Rest Show Custom Message

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

I'm using admin on rest. Sometimes I must show message to user. I'm using alert() function for now but this is worst. How can I show this notification? I didn't find the command for this.

[image: THIS]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are simple snackbars from material-ui:

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/snackbar